# C# Close window when process is started

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, for-loop

i have a WPF window which should close when the process "TeamViewer" is started.

Unfortunately I can't manage to build a suitable loop. Can you help me?

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


       Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("TeamViewer");
       do
        {
            this.Close();
        }
       while (pname.Length > 0);

    }
```

Greetings
iSteffen

Comment: Show what you tried so that someone can build on that.

Comment: Sry, i have Update my Post

Comment: Your code checks only once if process is running, inside the loop it doesn't check. Your code will hang.

Comment: You should yield, do read about waitforSingleObject

Comment: Sry but how could such a thing look then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for the process "TeamViewer" inside a loop, and on finding any instance of it, you can exit your form.
Example code, this one watches for Notepad instance , you can modify it to your needs.

```
     do
     {
         Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
         if (null != proc)
         {
              if (proc.Length > 0)
              {
                   //if any notepad process is running, then exit
                    return;
              }
         }

         //wait for some time, there are other efficient wait mechanisms
         Thread.Sleep(500); //wait for half sec

     }while(true);
```

Comment: Alternately instead of Thread.Sleep, you could also use `Task.Delay`, refer MS docs for examples.

Comment: Be aware that Thread.Sleep will block the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have now managed it with Anand Sowmithiran's solution.